# Why can't I bind javascript submit() with variables together?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a variable `targetForm` and tried to bind it with `submit()`. However, the bound function doesn't catch submit event when I call a function and trigger variable to submit form.

```
var targetForm;

function Add_Notice_Message(evt){

    alert('set up form');

    targetForm = document.notification_form;
    targetForm.classname= 'TTWForm';
    targetForm.method = "post";
    targetForm.action = '';
    targetForm.novalidate = '';

    alert('beforesubmmit'); 
    targetForm.submit();
}

$( targetForm ).bind(
    "submit",
    function( event ){
        alert('submit');

        var $form = $(this), type;
        type = $form.find('#type').val();

        var options = {
            category:'projects',
            message: 'Sample Notification'
        };

        notifications.createNotification(options);
        return false;
    }
);
```

Comment: what do you want to do, clear your questions with code

Comment: Do you define `targetForm` before binding to it? It doesn't appear so, so `bind` won't be binding to anything.

Comment: You bind the submit event, and then replace the value of `targetForm`. How do you expect jQuery to keep track of this change?

Comment: Check the value of variable targetForm..is it contain formobject which you are expecting? can you get the id of the targetFOrm?

Comment: Tanks you guys. The purpose of it is that I wanna define multi-form to establish websockets. It has been solved. Thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're binding the variable before it gets the value.

you should set the variable once (maybe outside the Add_Notice... function) and then bind it.

Comment: I define "targetForm" at the first line. It is outside of "Add_Notice_Message" function, isn't it. It is still not working.

Comment: Set the variable inline in the declaration line... var targetForm=$('#notification_form');